Illustrating QnAs with pictures, that have tags like pornography, sexuality etc
Illustrating QnAs with pictures, that have tags like pornography, sexuality, etc, is allowed or not?
Would that bother someone? On the other hand it will attract more user traffic:)

Could you elaborate a bit more? I don't really understand what you are hinting at.

@StevenJeuris Sir, thats why i thought pictures are important.

Illustrations can be used to assist in answering questions, less so are needed to assist in asking questions. 
Any illustration that would be useful for such purpose would involve the brain or a conceptualized diagram of a theory or process. In no way would pictures depicting pornography or sexuality be relevant or helpful for this site. In fact they would contravene the sites policies.
But you already know the answer to this.
See the help section.
The idea is to increase traffic with on topic posts.
Last time I checked we didn't have a pornography  tag.
